# Javascript remove string between two ' / '

Tags: javascript, string, split, substring, splice

I'm looking for some help with this, I'm new learning Javascript, and I want to remove the last folder name inside a path.

Example:  `/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/` is my current path, and I want to get the result like `/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
var path =  '/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/';
var splitPath = path.split('/');//[0] = '', [1] = FOLDER1, [2] = FOLDER2, [3] = FOLDER3
var finalPath = "/" + splitPath[1]+  "/"+ splitPath[2] + "/";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
var path =  '/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/';

var splitPath = path.split('/');    // ["", "FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", "FOLDER3", ""]

splitPath.shift();    // ["FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", "FOLDER3", ""]
splitPath.pop();    // ["FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", "FOLDER3"]
splitPath.pop();    // ["FOLDER1", "FOLDER2"]

var result = "/" + splitPath.join("/") + "/";    // "/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/"

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another way:

```
'/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/'.replace(/(\w*\/)$/, '');
//gives you: "/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/"
```

one more:

```
var s = "FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/";

var ss = s.replace(/\/$/, '');
ss.substring(0, ss.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

another:

```
const [path1, path2] = "FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/".split("/")
console.log('path: ', `/${path1}/${path2}/`);
```

another:

```
var s = "FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/";

const [newPath] = s.split(/(\w+\/)$/)
//"FOLDER1/FOLDER2/"
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let path = "/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/"

let result = path.split("/").filter((el,idx, arr) => idx < arr.length - 2).join("/") + "/"

console.log(result)
```